# Xilinx ISE VHDL for loop limit 8190

Tags: for-loop, vhdl, xilinx

I am building a 16bit subtraction module. I know there are maybe better ways to implement it but I am asked to do the simplest way for a homework. I wrote the one line code and when I went to test I created a testbench with 2 foor loops of 0 to 65535 for the inputs. Problem is that when you run this and go to the subtractions 6-5 to 6-8 and 7-4 until 7-9, you get wrong values. I happens with other numbers too when they are approaching the 0 result. I couldnt find the pattern thou. I am posting the code for you to please test it and give me some feedback. I tried with the unsigned and numeric libraries, and the std_logic, unsigned and signed types and in all the cases I got the same error.

The error stars when the number of iterations exceeds 8191 (2^13 - 1). If the loop goes from 0 to 8190 works great. So it might be a limit but I didnt get a warning or found something on the internet. A workaround that I tried was starting a new loop (from 8191 until another number, you can uncomment this in the tb code) after the first loop. It worked. However, if -for example- you change the first loop to go from 0 to 8193, the frist loop still ends in 8190 and then starts the second loop. I stopped there. Too weird.

Anyway, in Multisim from Altera I get it working nicely. So it must be a problem with Xilinx or I am missing something.

code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity addop is
   port (
      input_0  : in  signed(15 downto 0);
      input_1  : in  signed(15 downto 0);
      output   : out signed(15 downto 0)
   );
end addop;

architecture Behavioral of addop is

begin

   --add_process: process(input_0, input_1)
   --begin
      output <= input_0 - input_1;
   --end process add_process;

end Behavioral;
```

testbench code: (at the begining I ran 6-7 to see if maybe the tool/library was wrong but it is not xD)

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
 
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
 
ENTITY tb_addop IS
END tb_addop;
 
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_addop IS 
 
    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)
 
    COMPONENT addop
    PORT(
         input_0 : IN  signed(15 downto 0);
         input_1 : IN  signed(15 downto 0);
         output : OUT  signed(15 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;
    

   --Inputs
   signal input_0 : signed(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal input_1 : signed(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    --Outputs
   signal output : signed(15 downto 0);
   -- No clocks detected in port list. Replace <clock> below with 
   -- appropriate port name 
 
   --constant <clock>_period : time := 10 ns;
   subtype Range_Type is integer range 0 to 8190;--65535
 
BEGIN
 
    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: addop PORT MAP (
          input_0 => input_0,
          input_1 => input_1,
          output => output
        );

      -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;  
input_0 <= x"0006";
input_1 <= x"0007";
      
      -- insert stimulus here 
      wait for 10ns;
input_0 <= x"0000";
input_1 <= x"0000";
      wait for 10ns;
      
      for i in Range_type loop--65535 loop
         for j in Range_type loop--65535 loop
            wait for 10ns;
            input_1 <= input_1 + x"0001";
         end loop;
--         for j in 8191 to 9000 loop--65535 loop
--            wait for 10ns;
--            input_1 <= input_1 + x"0001";
--         end loop;
         input_1 <= (others => '0');
         input_0 <= input_0 + x"0001";
      end loop;

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

check simulation at 3 932 330 ns and 4 587 680ns.

PS: first time in stackoverflow :D thanks in advance

Comment: Try to make `output` of type `signed(16 downto 0)`

Comment: Simulation can be stopped at 6.4 ms to capture the subtractions you note (6-7 to 6-8, 7-4 to 7-9, 3932339ns and 4587680ns). None appear to have wrong results with a different simulator. Adding specific input values, expected output values and wrong output values to your question would provide a [mcve]. However on the surface there does appear to be an ISIM bug. Xilinx likely doesn't provide support. A different simulator could be used, a testbench isn't synthesized. You can trust FPGA synthesis to produce working adding hardware in general and get full coverage with fewer test vectors.

Comment: Enhance the testbench to check the outputs and assert they are correct/report otherwise (and optionally stop on the first error : use report level Warning or Failure to carry on or stop).

Comment: @po.pe signed is just a representation so it doesnt change anything

Comment: @user1155120 yeah I do trust the implementation but I wanted to know about the similation tool behavior

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'll try that. thanks